# CSS position absolute do not extend beyond the left most of container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table where each cell has additional description that is displayed underneath it on hover.

- I want to display the description directly under the cell only when hovered.
- The description should be left aligned with the cell unless it extends beyond the bounds of the table at which point it should become right aligned with the end of the table.

I have been able to make things left aligned however I have failed to find a way to ensure the description doesn't extend beyond the end.

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/9en4v2as/3/):**

```css
.description {
  display: none;
}
table {
  position: relative;
}
td:hover .description {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
}
td:last-child:hover .description {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="value">Value1</div>
      <div class="description">Description of Value1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="value">Value2</div>
      <div class="description">Description of Value2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="value">Value3</div>
      <div class="description">Description of Value3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="value">Value4</div>
      <div class="description">Unknown description length</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="value">Value5</div>
      <div class="description">Description of Value5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="value">Value6</div>
      <div class="description">Description of Value6</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript to check the position of the element.

Comment: I think you'll need JS to do this correctly

Answer (score 1):

With jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //get width table
    var w_table = $("table").width();
    var w_description;

    $("table td").hover(function(){

        //sum width td
        var w_td = 0;

       //get hover position
       var pos = $(this).index();

       $("table td").each(function(i){
           //sum width td until hover position
           w_td = w_td + $(this).width();
           if(i==pos)
              return false;
       });
       //get description width
       w_description = $(this).find(".description").width();

       //if width description+width td > width table
       if(w_description+w_td > w_table)
          $(this).find(".description").css("right",w_table-w_td-30);
    });
});
```

[Test here](https://jsfiddle.net/011cjkjr/)